# Run migration command once to create many table, each one with different migration id

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In my work it is usual to delete all tables in a database and then recreate them one by one with the migration files. I don't agree with this method of working but it is the one we have at the moment.

The process is usually a bit tedious and I would like to know if I could execute only once the command to make a migration of many tables but in a way that a different migration batch is assigned for each table created (for each file to be migrated).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `php artisan migrate:fresh` drops all database tables and then runs all migrations which sounds like what you are looking for

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but of course you could already create a simple artisan commands yourself that adjusts the migration IDs, and run that command after your migration command.

Comment: @apokryfos, thank you very much for your answer, but it doesn't help me because all migrations are generated with the same batch.